# php-cs-fixer stopped working after php 7.3 update

Tags: homebrew, php-7

I'm using Homebrew to manage both of them and they are up to date.

```
~ $ brew --version
Homebrew 1.8.4
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision a166; last commit 2018-12-08)

~ $ php --version
PHP 7.3.0 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2018 11:00:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.0, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

~ $ php-cs-fixer --version
PHP needs to be a minimum version of PHP 5.6.0 and maximum version of PHP 7.2.*.

~ $ brew upgrade php-cs-fixer
Error: php-cs-fixer 2.13.1 already installed
```

This happens when I try to use php-cs-fixer

```
~ $ php-cs-fixer fix file.php
PHP needs to be a minimum version of PHP 5.6.0 and maximum version of PHP 7.2.*.
```

So, I downloaded php@7.2 and php-cs-fixer.phar to test and it works that way.

```
~ $ /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.13/bin/php /Users/aaronk/php-cs-fixer.phar fix file.php
Loaded config default from "/Users/aaronk/.php_cs".
Using cache file ".php_cs.cache".
Paths from configuration file have been overridden by paths provided as command arguments.
   1) file.php

Fixed all files in 0.014 seconds, 10.000 MB memory used
~ $
```

So my question is, how do I get homebrew's php-cs-fixer to work?
Is homebrew doing something wrong here?

(p.s. is there a tag for php7.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by godbout, PHP-CS-Fixer does not yes support PHP 7.3. You can track the GitHub issue [[Meta] PHP 7.3 support #3697](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/3697), to follow the evolution of the situation. According to this issue, the following changes in PHP 7.3 still need to be adressed:

> - [Flexible Heredoc and Nowdoc Syntaxes](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/flexible_heredoc_nowdoc_syntaxes)
> - [list() Reference Assignment](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/list_reference_assignment)
> - instanceof now allows literals as the first operand, in which case the result is always false.
> - [Allow a trailing comma in function calls](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/trailing-comma-function-calls)
> - [hrtime function has been added](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2976)
> - is_countable function shall be handled as all other native functions

Answer (score 3):

The current version `"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.14"` now supports php 7.3. You could upgrade it and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Homebrew. It's `php-cs-fixer` itself that doesn't support PHP7.3. You would get the same issue through `composer`, with unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The [mentioned issues](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/3697) isn't related to the PH PC Fixer code, rather to it's features. It's clear missuse of `composer.json`, where are dependencies, not features.

PHP CS Fixer works fine on PHP 7.3, see [this PR](https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/pull/1227).

**This command allows you to install it on PHP 7.3**:

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Let me know if you came across any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify - PHP CS Fixer being run under PHP 7.3 may fix code written using syntax up to PHP 7.2. But if one would run tool on code written in 7.3, eg `is_null($foo, )` (trailing comma), then behavior of fixer is not stable (producing `null === $foo,` - still, with trailing comma), which is an issue.